# Validation <input type="file"> with JQuery Validation Plugin

Tags: jquery

I use [JQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) to validate my form and it works for all fields,
but when I try to use it for  `<input type="file" id="ProjectInformation">`

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#feedback-form").validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                form.submit();
            },
            rules: {
                Name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                ProjectInformation: {
                    extension: "doc,txt,pdf",
                }
            },
            messages: {
                Name: {
                    required: "Please enter a name",
                    minlength: "Name must consist of at least 2 characters"
                },
                ProjectInformation: {
                    extension: "Only .doc, .txt, and .pdf files allowed",
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I get error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined**
What's wrong?

Comment: What's the line that the error refers to? (It's probably in the plugin's js file)

Comment: Yes, it's here `    } catch(e) {
     if ( this.settings.debug && window.console ) {
      console.log( "Exception occurred when checking element " + element.id + ", check the '" + rule.method + "' method.", e );
     }
     throw e;
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I have chacked `extension` in Validation Plugin and found that in that example they use `|` instead of `,` So
Try using..

```
extension: "doc|txt|pdf",
```

Comment: Nope, I tried, it doesnt work too, `The allowed file extensions, seperated via "|" (or a comma, ",")` [link](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/CustomMethods/extension#extension)